# Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I am trying to execute a ruby script:

```
def mymethod
  variable = `ruby /home/user/Test.rb`
  exec variable
  raise "Failed: #{variable}" unless variable.blank?
end
```

Test.rb script is present in the mentioned path, even then i get an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - )
```

The Test.rb content:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/smtp'
require 'pp'
require 'mysql'
require 'yaml'
message = "MESSAGE_END
G Name <MyEmailAddress>
To: G Name <MyEmailAddress>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test
This is a test mail"
Net::SMTP.start('webserver') do |smtp|
smtp.send_message message, 'EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress'
end
```

When I manually run this script. It sends the mail as expected.

Comment: What sort of output does `Test.rb` produce?

Comment: Do you want to open the file or what?

Comment: what about require 'Test.rb' in your controller?

Comment: @Vinay: Just want to execute the ruby script by doing ruby file.rb and it will send a mail

Comment: @Hivltg trying to understand the question a `backtick` followed by exec and raise after exec well first of all the `backtick` would execute the  code then what the need of `exec` secondly the  `raise` statement after `exec` which would never be executed what are trying to achieve

Comment: @Viren: Sorry about the raise part. I followed some link and pasted that code into my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to

```
require 'open-uri'
```

So,

```
require '/home/user/Test.rb'  
require 'open-uri'  # sometimes without this line, we get the exact error message in ruby on rails..
```

(or)

Try to reboot your server, sometimes its fix it..